# Are search urls for tags containing + (plus) sign double urldecoded?

Tags: support, tags, hyperlinks, search

While composing a question on meta, I was naively creating and adding together tagged search urls and wanted to search for C++ tag too.

I naïvely put a link as this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+c%2b%2b

which then gets transferred over the wire (as seen in wireshark) as

```
GET https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum+c%2b%2b HTTP/1.1
```

but if you click on it, it searches for [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

I then played with it, and found that when I put the url

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum c%2b%2b

into my browsers address line (firefox 29 btw.) then it works fine. This gets transferred over the wire as

```
GET https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum%20c%2b%2b HTTP/1.1
```

so my current "workaround" is to use it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum%20c%2b%2b) to link since using the space directly [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sum c%2b%2b). (sic!)

**Is this all intentional behaviour?** It seems that there is some double url decoding going on (c%2b%2b => c++ => c).

While this is mostly not a problem when copypasting uris, this is quite annoying when manually constructing them, e.g. when writing meta posts.

Comment: +1, looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, there's a special case for [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (and perhaps similar tags).

When you go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost and look at the related tags, there's

- [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) pointing to `/questions/tagged/boost%20c%2b%2b`
- [boost-asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-asio) pointing to `/questions/tagged/boost+boost-asio`
- [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) pointing to `/questions/tagged/boost+multithreading`
- [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) pointing to `/questions/tagged/boost%20c%2b%2b11`