# Link to SO search URL with multiple tags sometimes drops all but first

Tags: support, tags, search

In [this comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130376/creating-a-windows-installer-from-os-x?noredirect=1#comment227305_130376), I included a link with this URL:
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx+windows+installer`

which is intended to search SO for the tags `[osx] [windows] [installer]`.

On Windows 7 Chrome & Android Firefox it functions as expected, but on Windows 7 Firefox & IE, the URL gets changed into: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx`

Did I do something incorrectly, or is this a bug? Is it a side effect of [support for `c++` tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254689/are-search-urls-for-tags-containing-plus-sign-double-urldecoded)?

Comment: Are you logged in when using Firefox or IE?

Comment: Are you using the new navigation?

Comment: @Stijn no I was not logged in when it failed & I was logged in when it worked. Logged out in Windows Chrome & it failed, so that seems to be the common factor.

Comment: @Gothdo uncertain; how do I check?

Comment: @Pikalek You can check it on the [preferences page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/).

Comment: I don't have access to Windows 7, can you try it with the following link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx%20windows%20installer

Comment: @Gothdo I am not using the new navigation.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan your link behaves the same way for me, uses all tags if logged in, drops all but the first when not

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous users may only search one tag at a time.

From [Multiple tags search broken when searching as anonymous user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243960/multiple-tags-search-broken-when-searching-as-anonymous-user) on MSE:

> We only allow a single tag search for anonymous users at this time.
>
> So yes, we will strip out the remaining tags when searching as anonymous.

According to the comments on the answer there, it was a quick fix for a DDOS attack, and it has never been changed. I think an argument can at least be made for noting it on the page when this happens. (This was also brought up in the comments on that answer.)