# How can I use a composite tag in an answer?

Tags: support, tags, answers, hyperlinks

For the Java tag, I can use [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), i.e., `[tag:java]`, but I want to use a composite tag, e.g., for both, `duration` and `java` which would open the page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duration+java

Is such a feature available?

Comment: I dont think this is possible

Comment: No shorthand that I know of, but you could always just do it as a normal hyperlink of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, as of November 2, 2022, such feature doesn't exist in Stack Overflow.

The workaround is to add the hyperlink manually.

HTML

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duration+java">`duration` `java`</a>
```

result:

[`duration` `java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duration+java)

Markdown

```
[`duration` `java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duration+java)
```

result:

[`duration` `java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duration+java)

P.S. Some people share their userscripts to tasks like this in https://stackapps.com/

Related

- [How to search post with multiple tags but not containing a specific one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261383/1595451)
- [Link to SO search URL with multiple tags sometimes drops all but first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335118/1595451)

Reference

- [Comment formatting | Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)